# Class Functions Object Oriented Program

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm learning classes and objects in C++. I'm trying to ask to enter their favorite sports and their gender and executing it through void display. I'm getting 3 errors.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Question
{
    private:

    int basketball;
    int gender;

    public: 

    void getsports();
    void getgender();
    void display();
};

void Question::getsports()
{
    int sport; 
    cout << "Whats your favorite sports?" << endl; 
    cin >> sport;
}

void Question::getgender()
{
    int gender;
    cout << "Whats you gender?"; 
    cin >> gender; 
}

void Question::display()
{
    cout << "Your answers are " << sport << gender; // line 39 is here
}

int main()
{
    Question obj;
    obj.display(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Here is the error:

```
"sport" is undefined line 39
'Sport' undeclared identifier line 39
```

Comment: Copy/paste the full error messages into the question (as text).

Comment: Okay I fixed it! Sorry first time posting a question on this website.

Comment: Please post all three of your error messages, and indicate where in the code they refer to. (errors usually show which line number they're on, but we don't have the benefit of line numbers in your code here - so use comments to let us know where each error is occurring)

Comment: I can't see any variable named `Sport` in your code. After `#include <vector` a `>` is missing.

Comment: In this function `void Question::display()
{
cout << "Your answers are " << sport << gender; 
}` you use `sport` but `sport` is not a class member variable. You also print `gender` but `gender` that you use in `getgender()` is a different variable, local to the `getgender()`  function.

Comment: 1) You never actually assigned anything, anywhere as you never called the functions `getgender()` and `getsport()`.
2) `sports` is not a member of class `Question`. I believe that instead of `int basketball` you should go for `int sport`.
3) Both your 'get*` methods are assigning to a variable that exists in the context of the function they are called. How about assigning it to your object?

Comment: I thought i declared the sport and gender at void getsports and void getgender since I put int gender and int sports on each void function.

Comment: @John probably none of those, as I'm not a big fan of basketball haha. Although I believe that using a `int` for it is wrong (oh, hey there `std::string`!), I'm jus trying to point out the errors on the code. The rest OP will figure out.

Comment: @EmilyMike Look at the class member variables. `sport` is not among those. `gender` is - but you declare a new `gender` variable in `getgender()`, so the class member `gender` will not get assigned.

Comment: I added int sport to the private class and when I ran it, it gave me numbers as the output. Can someone show me a code on how they'll set this up.

Comment: Your member variables are `int`s - that is, they can store integers. Numbers are all you'll ever get out of those, unless you map the number to strings somehow. Maybe using a `std::array` of `std::string`s

Comment: variables declared in a function,as here sport is, can be accessed only in that function, and are lost outside of the function. Not what you want! should be in the class under privates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a walk through your code and see what is wrong.

Let's go through your class `Question`. It has two member variables: `int basketball` and `int gender`. Those are the variables that you want to assign a value to when running your code. In order to do that, you created two methods: `getsports()` and `getgender()`.

But what is the problem with those two methods? Well, first they are never called. Second both of them have `int` variables that are being assigned. Here's the catch: both those variables are declared inside the methods, so what happens when the method is done?

You're assigning values to local variables of your functions when what you really wanted is to assign those values to your class variables. One way to accomplish it is instead of using those variables inside the methods, use the ones of your object. As both methods `getsports()` and `getgender()` are part of your object, the variables `int basketball` and `int gender` are available on those methods. One way to access those variables is to use `this` operator, for example:

```
void Question::getgender(){
      cout << "Whats you gender?"; 
      cin >> this->gender
}
```

When it comes to the `void Question::display()` method, it is trying to access a variable named sport. But sport is not a member of your class `Question`. The members of your class, as we stated before, are `int basketball` and `int gender`. So, the easiest way here is to change `int basketball` for `int sports` for example.

Now let's jump right into your `main` function. You declare your object and right away you want to display its content. But have you ever assigned those values? So how about, instead of calling the `display()` method right away, call `getgender()` and `getsports()` before?

You'll probably end up with something like:

```
int main(){
    Question obj;
    obj.getgender();
    obj.getsports();
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

That's it. Also, bear in mind that `int` is probably not the type of variable that you want to store the name of a sport, for example. I suggest take a look at [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), for instance.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me out a lot!